# Laravel, how to run update on table column using old value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter, eloquent

I have a table of users with encrypted (not hashed) passwords.

I want to update rows that are using a certain encryption (not all rows are using this encryption)

I need to use the old value for the password, decrypt it, and encrypt it using a new encryption.

```
 $result = DB::connection('writer')
             ->table('users')
             ->where('pw', 'LIKE', 'oldEncryption')
             ->get();

 foreach($result as $r){
        $password = olddecrypt($r->pw);
        $newpassword = newencrypt($password);
        $r->pw = $newpassword;
 }

 DB::connection('writer')
     ->table('users')
     ->update($result);
```

heres the non working "pseudo code"
any good approach for this?

Comment: Encrypted passwords cannot be decrypted, just matched using the same encryption. You'd be better off forcing password resets.

Comment: i think your talking about hashing

Comment: Hmm. Yes, you are right. Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted. If they can be encrypted, they can be decrypted by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started in the right direction.

```
$users = DB::connection('writer')
              ->table('users')
              ->where('pw', 'LIKE', 'oldEncryption')
              ->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    DB::connection('writer')
        ->table('users')
        ->where('id', $user->id)
        ->update(['pw' => newencrypt(olddecrypt($user->pw))]);
}
```

`newencrypt` and `olddecrypt` I'm assuming are your own implementations.

Answer (score -2):

For a start we need to know what was the old encryption type, if it was md5 you can try md5 decryption websites but you won't find decryptions for all the passwords you have.

but if the old encryption method something more complex than md5, you won't be able to decrypt them using any method that I know of, you can just compare 2 encrypted values like in bcrypt which is used in laravel.